# The first species having circle of Willis (circulus arteriosus cerebri)?

Tags: evolution, anatomy, neuroanatomy

I know mammals are not the only species that have this anatomical unit (i.e. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3982101/).

But I was wondering what was the **first species** that had a similar structure in their brain (or brain-like organ). Do we know this?

Comment: it is interesting question